# Python Logging module: custom loggers

Tags: python, logging

I was trying to create a custom attribute for logging (caller's class name, module name, etc.) and got stuck with a strange exception telling me that the LogRecord instance created in the process did not have the necessary attributes. After a bit of testing I ended up with this:

```python
import logging

class MyLogger(logging.getLoggerClass()):
    value = None

logging.setLoggerClass(MyLogger)

loggers = [
    logging.getLogger(),
    logging.getLogger(""),
    logging.getLogger("Name")
]

for logger in loggers:
    print(isinstance(logger, MyLogger), hasattr(logger, "value"))
```

This seemingly correct piece of code yields:

```python
False False
False False
True True
```

Bug or feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the source code we can see the following:

```
root = RootLogger(WARNING)
def getLogger(name=None):
    if name:
        return Logger.manager.getLogger(name)
    else:
        return root
```

That is, a root logger is created by default when the module is imported. Hence, every time you look for the root looger (passing a false value such as the empty string), you're going to get a `logging.RootLogger` object regardless of any call to `logging.setLoggerClass`.

Regarding the logger class being used we can see:

```
_loggerClass = None
def setLoggerClass(klass):
    ...
    _loggerClass = klass
```

This means that a global variable holds the logger class to be used in the future.

In addition to this, looking at `logging.Manager` (used by `logging.getLogger`), we can see this:

```
def getLogger(self, name):
    ...
            rv = (self.loggerClass or _loggerClass)(name)
```

That is, if `self.loggerClass` isn't set (which won't be unless you've explicitly set it), the class from the global variable is used.

Hence, it's a feature. The root logger is always a `logging.RootLogger` object and the other logger objects are created based on the configuration at that time.

Answer (score 2):

`logging.getLogger()` and `logging.getLogger("")` don't return a `MyLogger` because they return the root logger of the logging hierarchy, as described in the [logging documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html):

> logging.getLogger([name])
>
> Return a logger with the specified name or, if no name is specified, return a logger which is the root logger of the hierarchy.

Thus, as you have the logger set up:

```
>>> logging.getLogger()
<logging.RootLogger object at 0x7d9450>
>>> logging.getLogger("foo")
<test3.MyLogger object at 0x76d9f0>
```

I don't think this is related to the KeyError you started your post with. You should post the code that caused that exception to be thrown (`test.py`).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've edited the question.
But I think that this behavior is not what one would expect to happen.

Comment: Why is it not what you would expect to happen? It is *precisely* what the documentation says will happen when no name is specified.

Comment: Even though this is what the documentation says, it is counter-intuitive. Setting a class for loggers, I would expect _all_ loggers to have that class, including the root one and excluding the ones instantiated already.